# Reactionrole not working discord.js javascript

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create reactionrole for ny Discord bot using JavaScript. Everytime I send it the embed gets sent, but when one reacts to the emoji nothing happens. I tried everything and still can't fix it, please help.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = 902923957483741234;
        const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Yellow Team");
        const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Blue Team");
 
        const yellowTeamEmoji = '';
        const blueTeamEmoji = '';
 
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#000000')
            .setImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Flag_of_Chaudfontaine.svg/1200px-Flag_of_Chaudfontaine.svg.png')
            .setTitle('Alright Dumbfucks, Choose a Damn Color!')
            .setDescription('Choosing The Color Will Determine What Role You get!\n\n'
                + `${yellowTeamEmoji} This Emoji is For Yellow.\n`
                + `${blueTeamEmoji} That is For Blue.`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
        messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(blueTeamEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(blueTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(blueTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and specify what the problem is/what did you try and not just give your current code.

Comment: hello, after some reviews and editing your question was reopened (thanks for your edits!); however, you will help others help you if you describe what you expect to happen when an emoji is sent

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess is, the check `reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji` is not valid since `yellowTeamEmoji` is emoji content, not emoji name. You should log what actually comes in `reaction.emoji` and `reaction` and adapt your check, may be it even shouldn't use `reaction.emoji`, for instance `reaction.message.text === yellowTeamEmoji`